# Django REST Framework: What's really the difference between validate_<fieldname> and validate?

Tags: validation, django-rest-framework

I am performing a custom field-level validation in my serializer that requires referencing another field.

Looking at the examples in the [Validation documentation](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#validation), I'm not clear on whether I should use `validate_<fieldname>` or `validate`. It looks like both have the `attrs` dictionary, so from `validate_<fieldname>` I can just as easily reference another field as from `validate` (even though the description for `validate` indicates that you should use it for accessing multiple fields). So why are there both options? In my case, which option is correct to use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Raising a `ValidationError` inside `validate_<foo>()` will result in a field error.

```
{'foo': ['Not a fooish value.']}
```

Raising a `ValidationError` inside `validate()` will result in non-field error.

```
{'non_field_errors': ['Foo and bar are not compatible.']}
```

> So why are there both options?

Partly because of the above, and partly because the serializer API mirrors Django's form API where possible.  There's some differences where needed, but the `validate` and `validate_<foo>` style is similar.

> In my case, which option is correct to use?

You judgement call, based on which error message is more appropriate.

Comment: Neil - `attrs` is the input to the serializer as a dictionary before it's been validated and restored into a fully fledged object instance.  Off the top of my head I guess that might be to do with some of the input already having been validated at the point you're accessing it.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. Is there any way to pass additional parameters to validate_foo, like for example the object's id?

Comment: If it's an update then `self.object` holds a reference to the instance.

Comment: Cool! What about request.user? What I actually need for my validation on the field is the logged in user. Apologies if this is in the docs somewhere.

Comment: `self.context` is a dictionary of any extra context for the serializer.  The generic views will populate `request`, so you can use `self.context['request'].user`.  Mentioned [here](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#including-extra-context) but I think it maybe needs to be more prominent and/or explained further.

Comment: Thanks Tom, and congratulations on DRF. It is truly a remarkable bit of software, a joy to learn and use.

And yes, it's a bit a ambiguous in the docs :) That link (which I have read several times) makes you think that you have to explicitly pass context, while you actually don't. Also, would be great to know exactly what's in `self.context`